# How to set table schema at table name with Cake?

Tags: postgresql, cakephp

PostgreSQL, Oracle and many other DBMS's use SCHEMA, so, the table name is

```
schema_name.table_name
```

But CakePHP manuals not say anithing about this. What about Model, View and Controller names in the CakePHP defaults?  I can use a solution like prefix, that is, where the same schema name will be used at all database operations.

---

PS1: please not to be confused with [method Modelschema](http://api.cakephp.org/class/model#method-Modelschema), and questions about accessing this method.

PS2: the [Bill's 2006 solution](http://cakephp.1045679.n5.nabble.com/Schema-support-in-Postgres-td1257601.html) is not the better one, because is not updated (I am using CakePHP2) and is not a "official cakePHP solution".

PS3: database.php have some schema attribute? What the link to CakePHP documentation?

Comment: You specify the schema in your database.php... or are you asking for choosing the schema per query?

Comment: Well, I need both solutions, but the first one is a good beginning... See (edited) PS3, can I specify like prefix, `class DATABASE_CONFIG {... $default  'schema' => 'MySCHEMA', ... }`?

Answer (score 1):

Good news for me, there are [CakePHP 2.0 documentation about SQL-Schema](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/configuration.html)... No other documentation or examples, but a starting point...

Answer (score 1):

In CakePHP you must define more database config.

**In CakePHP 2:**

- set the 'schema' param to your config
- create new configs for all of your schema
- use the right schema in your models

For example, database conf:

```
public $default = array(
        'datasource' => 'Database/Postgres',
        'persistent' => false,
        'host'       => 'localhost',
        'login'      => 'my_db_user', 
        'password'   => 'my_db_passw', 
        'database'   => 'my_project_db', 
        'prefix'     => '',
        'encoding'   => 'utf8',
        'schema'     => 'postgres'
    );
public $other_schema = array(
        'datasource' => 'Database/Postgres',
        'persistent' => false,
        'host'       => 'localhost',
        'login'      => 'my_db_user', 
        'password'   => 'my_db_passw', 
        'database'   => 'my_project_db', 
        'prefix'     => '',
        'encoding'   => 'utf8',
        'schema'     => 'other_schema'
    );
```

If you want to use it in a model:

```
class AppModel extends AppModel {
    public $useDbConfig = 'other_schema';
}
```

In CakePHP3 is the same way, just there the database is config/app.php and you must use

```
use Cake\Datasource\ConnectionManager;
$connection = ConnectionManager::get('default');
```